# Can you put code in alerts for app script

Tags: javascript, string, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to app script and I was just wondering if there was a way to input a cell value into an alert.

I tried

```
var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
var winScreeen = ui.alert('Win:',sr.getRange('U5').getValue())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
var winScreeen = ui.alert('Win:',sr.getRange('U5').getValue())
```

use

```
var winScreeen = ui.alert('Win:' + sr.getRange('U5').getValue())
```

The above used `+` to concatenate two values.

Answer (score 0):

#### Another way to alert

```
function myalert() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(`win:${ss.getRange("Sheet0!A2").getValue()}`);
}
```

[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)